# Building a central Neo4j graph server

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I want to build a central neo4j graph db server (not an embedded one) that will store millions of information and its many relations. I have tens of threads running on various servers, these threads process some information and updates it to this central repository. Is it possible with neo4j? If so, then how effectively can it be built?

kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely consider using the [REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api.html).